# × Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, react-hooks

**I have tried a lot to iterate over the object with map function but it gives me this error again and again. I am beginner in React JS. here is the Code below. i have made an API in Django for fetching the TODO list tasks in my React JS Application**

*I am using axios to fetch the task from API & i have checked from console.log that the function which fetch the tasks from API is working Prefectly but when i iterate over those task it gives me the error written in the title*

> Here is my TaskList.js Component

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'   
import Task from './Task'

async function TaskList() { 
    let all_tasks= await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/read')
    console.log('all tasks rec-d from getAllTasks are', all_tasks);
    console.log('& the type is: ', typeof(all_tasks));
    return (
        <div className="TaskList">
            {
                all_tasks.map(function(task){
                    console.log('the task i m going to give to Task compont. is: ',task);
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <p>the task title is {task.title}</p>
                            <Task task={task} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

async function getAllTasks(url){
    let resp = await axios.get(url); 
    console.log('the type of resp in getAllTasks: ', typeof(resp));
    let all_tasks= await resp.data  
    console.log('the type of resp in getAllTasks.data : ', typeof(all_tasks));
    return all_tasks;
}

export default TaskList
```

*i also use a Task Component which i imported on 3rd Line on above code*

> and here is the code of that component Task.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

function Task({task}) {
    console.log('the task i rec-d in Task.js is: ',task);
    return ( 
        <div className="task-card">
            <div className="task-title">{task.title}</div>
            <div className="btns">
                <div className="delete">Delete</div>
                <Link to='/edit'>
                    <div className="Edit">Edit</div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div> 
    )
}

export default Task
```

Comment: Is `TaskList` supposed to be a React component? You can't issue side-effects, especially asynchronous effect, from the body of function components. React doesn't render its UI asynchronously. The render should be a pure, synchronous function.

Comment: Please show `all_tasks`

Comment: You should use `useEffect` for fetching data + `useState` to store and render data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on `TaskList` component. I would suggest you to modify your code in this way:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'   
import Task from './Task'

function TaskList() { 
    const [all_tasks, setAllTask] = useState();

    async function getAllTasks(url){
       let resp = await axios.get(url); 
       console.log('the type of resp in getAllTasks: ', typeof(resp));
       let all_tasks= await resp.data  
       console.log('the type of resp in getAllTasks.data : ', typeof(all_tasks));
       return all_tasks;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       (async () => {
          let newTask = await getAllTasks('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/read');
          setAllTask(newTask);
          console.log('all tasks rec-d from getAllTasks are', newTask);
          console.log('& the type is: ', typeof(newTask));
       })()
    }, [])
    
    
    return (
        <div className="TaskList">
            {
                all_tasks.map(function(task){
                    console.log('the task i m going to give to Task compont. is: ',task);
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <p>the task title is {task.title}</p>
                            <Task task={task} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default TaskList;
```

Explanation:

1. Removed async from component (you can't init an async component);
2. If you need to render some, you need to init a state variable using `useState` hook;
3. Move `getAllTasks` function inside component's body;
4. Use an `useEffect` hook to fetch data from API (by doing this one time on component's mounting (bracket `[]` as `useEffect`'s second parameter means this));

Comment: now after following the step.. it working properly

Answer (score 0):

problem with above code is the `async` word before `TaskList`.

In React every component must return a valid HTML content.

And the `async` functions always returns a promise. In your code, indeed you are returning the valid JSX(HTML) but internally it is getting wrapped inside a promise due to `async` keyword. and your component is returning a promise
instead of a JSX.

To solve this issue, remove the async keyword. And use `useEffect`.